# Adding scale of image zoom displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, image, user-interface

I want to add x,y-scale of an image in a wpf application. Something like:

[image: Image in WPF applciation.]

This screen shot is from MATLAB. My pan and zoom in WPF is working fine. The numbers shown here are number of rows(columns). When I zoom or pan, the display content (rows/columns visible) will change too, so the scale should change accordingly.

I am looking for hints/tips because currently I am not sure where to start. I Googled but could not find something useful. (commercially available solutions are also fine)

Comment: Is this somethign along the lines you are looking for? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21097/PictureBox-Zoom

Comment: no. its not. I will update question to make it more clear.

Comment: The scale transform is a single double value from 0 to the current zoom level.  You will need a linear interpolation to compute the interim values you are showing.  It can be problematic if the scale is, for example 3, and you want 10 interim stops because linear interpolation does not compute exact integers the way it's shown in your exhibit.

Comment: i am thinking on same track. but then I need to add n-textblocks, dynamically. Any tip on how to add textblocks as i change zoom or pan?